# Velocity Template Engine: How to check if variable is set within macro via passed parameter

Tags: java, velocity

I currently do have a working method which checks whether or not a variable is set.
I do it like this

```
CHECKING EACH VARIABLE:
#if($!{vh})
vh instance found!<br>
Classname: ${vh.class.name}<br>
#end
#if($!{su})
su instance found!<br>
Classname: ${su.class.name}<br>
#end
```

This will currently print this:

> CHECKING EACH VARIABLE: 
>   vh instance found!
>   Classname: de.integration.commons.VelocityXPathHelper
>
> su instance found!
>   Classname: de.integration.commons.StringUtils

Hint: I injected theese variables into the context before.

Since I do need to check for a lot of variables, and injected Variables differ sometimes, I created a macro who is supposed to do the same, combined with a loop over an array of strings who contains known injected variables like this:

```
#* Macro - checkIfVariableExists
This macro checks if variable exists with the quit reference notation
check http://velocity.apache.org/engine/devel/user-guide.html#quiet-reference-notation for more information *#
#macro (checkIfVariableExists $variablename)
    #if($!{variablename})
        $variablename instanz found!<br>
        Classname: ${variablename.class.name}<br>
    #end
#end

RESULT FROM LOOP:
#set( $toCheck = ["vh","su","anothervariable","...","....", "....."] )
#foreach( $value in $toCheck )
    #checkIfVariableExists($value)
#end
```

However, this will not work and result into this output:

> RESULT FROM LOOP: vh instanz found!
>   Classname: java.lang.String
>   su instanz found!
>   Classname: java.lang.String

How do I make this work? I do understand that value is a String, however I want to use the value of it as I did with my first approach. Any ideas? Im using velocity engine 1.7 and Im not able to change to a higher Version.

Answer (score 1):

If you are checking, what is available in the Context, you also could use the Velocity ContextTool (https://velocity.apache.org/tools/3.0/apidocs/org/apache/velocity/tools/generic/ContextTool.html).

It is available since VelocityTools version 2.0 (this does not correspond to the Velocity version!), and you can use

```
$context.keys
```

to find all variables that are available in the context. (It is a `Set`, so method `contains` would work.)